# $h$ homeomorphism, $h(x)$ and $h(y)$ in different components in $h(X)$ implies $x, y$ in different components in $X$?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Homeomorphism $h:X\rightarrow Y$, if $h(x)$ and $h(y)$ lie in different connected components in h(X), is it true that x and y lie in different connected components in X?

I'm thinking for any two connected $U,V$ sets contain $h(x),h(y)$ respectively, they are disjoint. By continuity of $h^{-1}$, we have this is also true for $h^{-1}(U)$ and $h^{-1}(V)$ in $X$. Vice versa.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the connection between $f$ and $h$?

Comment: Yes, it is true.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo, should all about h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean $h(X)$ here? Remember that homeomorphisms preserve all the topological information. If $U$ and $V$ are disjoint in $Y$, taking the inverse of the homeomorphism keeps them disjoint. It's exactly the argument you mentioned. If that weren't the case then you could just use $h$ again and you'd get that a connected component splits into two different connected components.